# Volume of a body formed by rolling a sphere inside an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, convex-optimization, volume

Is there any analytical solution or approximation to the volume of a body that is formed by the center of a sphere of radius $r$ that is rolling inside an ellipsoid?

The answer to the extreme limiting cases are obvious:

1. when the ratio of the smallest semi-axis of the ellipsoid to the sphere's radius is less than 1, $\frac{a_{min}}{r}\leq 1$, then $V=0$.
2. when $\frac{a_{min}}{r}>> 1$, then $V\rightarrow V_{ellipsoid}$.

Is there an analytical expression that quantifies $V$ as a function of the ellipsoid eigenvalues (i.e., semi-axes)? Note that, by definition, all points of this body are at least a distance of $r$ from the interior surface of the ellipsoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The surface is called an *offset surface*. It is unfortunately not an ellipsoid.
People who need this surface (or its planar equivalent) usually resort to approximations. See, e.g., the Wikipedia article on "[*parallel curves*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve)."

> Farouki, Rida T. "Conic approximation of conic offsets." *Journal of Symbolic computation* 23.2-3 (1997): 301-313.
>
> Anton, F., Emiris, I., Mourrain, B., & Teillaud, M. (2005, May). The offset to an algebraic curve and an application to conics. In *International Conference on Computational Science and its Applications* (pp. 683-696). Springer Berlin Heidelberg.